# Is my case statement broken by the use of outer apply?

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-refactor, case

I'm struggling with a case statement not working. Simple enough I need to supply a value of 0 where the question marks are. I have several other case statements which handle separate columns, but this is the simplest. I have used case statements with NULLS before and no issue. My best guess is the OUTER APPLY is screwing with things, but I can't find any documentation to back that up.

```
SELECT TOP 20
  GIVE_BACK1.CLUB_TOT 'B1_TOT',
  GC.CLUB_USER_VARBL3
FROM
  SUMMIT.CLUB_MBRSP GC
    OUTER APPLY
    (
      SELECT
        CASE 
          WHEN B1.CLUB_USER_VARBL3 IS NULL
            THEN '?????????????????????????????'
          ELSE
            B1.CLUB_TOT
        END AS 'CLUB_TOT'
      FROM
        SUMMIT.CLUB_MBRSP B1
      WHERE
        GC.ID = B1.ID
        AND
        (
          (
            GC.CLUB_USER_VARBL3 != 'LT'
            AND B1.CLUB_USER_VARBL3 = LEFT(GC.CLUB_USER_VARBL3,2) + CONVERT(varchar(2),(CONVERT(INT,RIGHT(GC.CLUB_USER_VARBL3,3))-1))
          )
        )
    ) GIVE_BACK1
```

This query yields this result set

```
NULL         FY88 
NULL         FY10 
NULL         FY01 
NULL         FY99 
NULL         FY97 
NULL         FY99 
NULL         FY97 
NULL         FY02 
NULL         FY01 
17525.00     FY85 
NULL         FY84
...
```

Any help getting the case statement working, and explanation of the issue or a refactoring would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Outer Apply is working like a Left Outer Join so when no row is returned by the Outer Apply a row filled with NULLs is returned.  I would question the need for the Outer Apply but placing a Coalesce(GIVE_BACK1.CLUB_TOT,0) in the SELECT list would fix the immediate issue.

Comment: Your right, the cross apply doesn't make much sense. Thanks for the answer and the critique!